# Can I change the language NPCs talk in?

Tags: battlefield-4

Is there any way to make the NPCs speak in a different language?  I still want the text and everything else in English, though.

Comment: So you want to know if there are subtitles for other languages.

Comment: no, i want voices in another language but text in english

Comment: Which is what [subtitles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_%28captioning%29) are.

Comment: @fbueckert He's asking about voice-over for the campaign (which doesn't exist as far as I know), not subtitles.

Comment: i don't want subtitles in another language, i want dialogue in another language but everything else in English.

Comment: @3ventic if you own battlefield 4 could you check?

Comment: Ok, that was confusing.  I've edited your question to try to make it clearer.

Comment: @user62393 If an answer isnt posted here by the time I get home (~4 hours), I will check - though I am pretty sure you cannot do this.

Comment: i got this from a guy who said there was a voice over but i didn't really believe him, it sounded too good to be true but i would still like to know if there is one

Comment: It might also help to specify the console/PC, seems much more likely on PC.

Comment: im getting it for the Xbox one

Answer (score 1):

On PS3, there is no voice-over option, don t know for XBOne, but it would be surprising.

Answer (score 1):

There is no voice over option. But you can buy a copy of the game that is set to a different language.